# Strange bug in JS code (maybe some variable state caching)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make a small game using JS and Canvas. It is the implementation from old "Stack Attack" 2D platformer from Siemens cellphones.

So I implemented some basic logic to spawn, move around and throw boxes.

Then I came across a very strange bahaviour: sometimes boxes are thrown at the same position within a small time slice, and my special "protecting" function that checks if the column is "available" for throwing at the current moment does not help. Thus the boxes overlap and are going down partly overlapping each other.

I don't know how to efficiently debug this, so I kindly ask to help me with this error. Maybe there is a simple logical mistake in my code that I did not notice.

I made a codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajrqMB

Function moving the boxes down:

```
function moveColumnDown(pos) {
   var b = []
   for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
      if (boxes[i].x / cw == pos) {
         b.push(boxes[i])
      }
   }
   for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
      if (i == 0 && b[i].y < height-3-ch ||
          i > 0 && b[i].y + ch < b[i-1].y) {
         for (var j = i; j < b.length; j++) {
            b[j].y += spd_y
         }
         break;
      }
   }
   cols_state[pos] = (b.length == 0 || b[b.length-1].y >= y_offset+ch)
}
```

I'm looking at this code and can't unserstand how even the top overlapping box is going down: the condition `i > 0 && b[i].y + ch < b[i-1].y` where `ch` is a single box height should not be satisfied for it anyway...

Also, this line

```
cols_state[pos] = (b.length == 0 || b[b.length-1].y >= y_offset+ch)
```

in the end of the function updates the column state. When the box get dropped, column state is set to `false`. After the box has moved down a little bit in the function `moveColumnDown()` the state is updated - to `false` again, I suppose. But still the next box gets dropped for some unknown reason. I thought that maybe they get dropped at the same tick, when the column state is still `true` - but even in this case assigning `false` in the `drop()` function should have mitigated the problem. But the problem still persists.

UPDATE: It seems that the number of dropped boxes in the model doesn't match the real number of displayed boxes (it is much bigger). That's also very strange. On this picture there is 46 boxes (not on the conveyor), but the `boxes[]` array contains 53 elements.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What you are saying "sometimes boxes are thrown at the same position" that is a bad starts, that will be very hard for anyone to troubleshoot/debug your problem... You must be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Also for games like this I strongly recommend you using a game engine, there are plenty of open source ones: https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines

Comment: @HelderSepu I mean, the positions where they are dropped are random. I added one more check (to make sure that the "dropped" box on the conveyor will not be dropped again under any circumstances). I'm not sure if the problem is gone, will do more testing. Anyway, it is strange that it did get dropped, because the column should have already been blocked at the next tick.